# Linux kernel page fault couning

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, page-fault

I'm currently making a project for school where we have to implement a new sys call in linux kernel that count the number of page faults inside a struct like this

```
struct pfstat {
int stack_low; //Number of times the stack was expanded after a page fault
int transparent_hugepage_fault; //Number of huge page transparent PMD fault
int anonymous_fault; //Normal anonymous page fault
int file_fault; //Normal file-backed page fault
int swapped_back; //Number of fault that produced a read-from swap to put back the page online
int copy_on_write; //Normal of fault which backed a copy-on-write;
int fault_alloced_page; //Number of normal pages allocated due to a page fault (no matter the code path if it was for an anonymous fault, a cow, ...).
 }
```

and access it with PID. I should also be able to set the task in pfstat mode.
I have already modified task_struct by inserting pfstat inside it and adding a pfmode. My problems is that I don't really understand where I could find the code that handle these different page fault and so increment there values.

I have found **do_page_fault** in *arch/x86/mm/fault.c* but it doesn't seems to handle all these faults. Should I also modified some functions such as **do_anonymous_page**, **do_linear_fault**, **do_swap_page**, **do_nonlinear_fault**, **do_wp_page** or do I miss understand something?

To summarize, I just don't find the code were I should increment all my struct members.

EDIT: I'm using kernel version 4.4.50.

Comment: Have you asked your professor or TA for assistance?

Comment: I do, but because we are sunday they haven't answer yet.